# Error while installing npm-java on Ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have latest `npm 6.7.0` version. I tried to install `npm-java` module but it gives following error. Here I can see permission issue but I am running it with root permission using `sudo`. What is the reason for this issue and how to get it fixed?

```
malintha@malintha-laptop:~$ sudo npm -g install java 

> java@0.11.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/java
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/java/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-44-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.11.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/malintha/.npm/_logs/2019-02-04T11_42_36_223Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it removing sudo from the installation command. Just run `npm install`java